# Converting UTC time to ISO 8601-like format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I would like to convert a UTC time to to the following format (IS0 8601).
Eg.

```
2000-01-01T17:00:00-05:00
```

Currently I'm using `UtcNow.Convert.ToString("s")`, which gives me the datetime in the format

```
2015-12-05T08:49:14
```

but this skips the time part after the `"-"` symbol.

Can anybody help on this ?

Comment: Is `-` between your time part and offset part means just `-` separator or it represents negative offset?

Comment: its just a - seperator

Comment: You say you have a UTC time but you want it to display a UTC offset, which by definition is zero.

Comment: If you *don't* have a UTC time, the [round trip (`"o"`) specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) will give something like `"2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000-07:00"`

Answer (score 3):

I think your format is *little* bit different than ISO 8601 format.

First of all, when you use any `z` format specifier, you always get `+` or `-` sign depends on your UTC Offset value is negative or positive.

Would be better to get your current local time zone utc offset, format it with `hh\\:mm` format and combine your formatted `UtcNow` value like;

```
var utcOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
var formattedOffset = utcOffset.ToString("hh\\:mm");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'-'" + formattedOffset));
```

Or you can use [The `"s"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Sortable) and format your offset part with `-` string literal as;

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s") + utcOffset.ToString("'-'hh\\:mm"));
```